# Does python use interning on generator objects? Weird behaviour with (i for i in range(n))

Tags: python, range, generator, string-interning

Why do these two loops not give the same result?  (Yes, I know the second version is bad style.  But I'd still expect it to give the same output.)

```
gen1 = range(3)
gen2 = range(3)
print("First attempt")
for i in gen1:
  for j in gen2:
    print(i,j)

gen1 = (i for i in range(3))
gen2 = (i for i in range(3))
print("Second attempt")
for i in gen1:
  for j in gen2:
    print(i,j)
```

Output using Python 3.6.9 (and I get the same results with Python 2.7.15):

```
First attempt
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
Second attempt
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`range` is its own type. It’s iterable, but not an *iterator* (or generator) – you can iterate over it multiple times, each time creating independent iterators:

```
>>> r = range(2)
>>> list(r)
[0, 1]
>>> list(r)
[0, 1]
>>> next(r)
TypeError: 'range' object is not an iterator
```

Generators, like from generator expressions, *are* iterators. When you iterate over them, you advance them.

```
>>> r = (1 + x for x in range(2))
>>> list(r)
[1, 2]
>>> list(r)
[]
```

```
>>> r = (1 + x for x in range(2))
>>> iter(r) is r
True
>>> next(r)
1
```

And, to answer the first question explicitly, this behaviour isn’t related to interning. During the first iteration of the `for i in gen1` loop, `gen2` is consumed, so the remaining iterations do nothing.

Comment: Ah, silly me, "for j in gen2" is only one line of code but gets executed three times.  Of course.  Thanks for the clear explanation.